# Python Cannot Import Name Django

Tags: python, django

I get the following error

```
File "/mnt/d/Protostar/server/src/api/ideas/serializers.py", line 2, in <module>                                     
from .models import Idea                                                                                            
ImportError: cannot import name 'Idea'
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Idea(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Idea

class IdeaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Idea
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have no idea why this isn't working, I've imported the same way in many projects before.

Here is the directory:
[image]

Comment: what about : ```from ideas.models import Idea``` ?

Comment: I already tried that I get the same issue.

Comment: Are `serializers.py` and `models.py` in the same folder and is there an `__init__.py` in the folder too?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same directory

Comment: can you import the model using django shell ? ```python manage.py shell```

Comment: Is the `models.py` you have shared the whole file? You may have some issue like a circular dependency

Comment: I've tried importing it in the console but I still get the same error

Comment: Yes its the whole file

Comment: If you import the models file and then run `dir` on it, does your model appear in the list? `from ideas import models; dir(models)`

Comment: When I ran that in teh shell i got ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'models']

Comment: You're not importing the correct `models.py` then, the imported `User` is not even appearing in the module

Comment: How would I fix this then

Comment: Try deleting `__pychache__` to eliminate the possibility that it's a caching issue. If the problem persists then I would suggest making sure you have defined `Idea` in the correct file

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have been importing from the wrong models.py all along I want to thank Lain Shelvington for helping me solve this stupid issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error says that, it is able to import the module models but couldn't find 'Idea' in that file. Probably it is not present in the same folder.

Please check if 'Idea' is present in the same models.py or may be in your IDE you opened a different models.py and got confused.